# Refining mixed to a known object type in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

We're trying to do type refinement in Flow to guard against values entering our application at the external interfaces. To do this we're using `mixed` and then trying to refine to known types, but Flow isn't make it easy!

The following seems like it should work, I've validated that the `mixed` type value matches the requirements of the `response` type.

```
type Response = { head: string }

const refineToResponse = (value: mixed): ?Response => {   
  if (value
    && typeof value === "object"
    && typeof value.head === "string") {

    return value;   
  }

  return null; 
};
```

But I just get a very unhelpful error message:

> ```
> 16:     return value;
>                ^^^^^ object. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
> 11: const refineToResponse = (value: mixed): ?Response => {
>                                               ^^^^^^^^ object type
> ```
>
> Property `head` is incompatible:
>
> ```
>  11: const refineToResponse = (value: mixed): ?Response => {
>                                                  ^^^^^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
>   8:   head: string
>              ^^^^^^ string
> ```

Edit:

[A link to the code on TryFlow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBKeAzjnAHYkEC8YA3mABZ4CGAJgFxgkYBOASwoBzMAF90AY0q8wfPFCF4AKnGJkZtMAAoAbqxgBXPNwC2AgB552ASm4B+deSq0AfAzCfUngVB36jPG9PMAAyULBsfDg-AOMwGkSwACI4ACMAKzxJDGTgz3DI3DwYsDi8ADoWDgSk5N5BEWSbBnQQuTwMQz4KMoNjAG4Q4Ilg+S6esApDGBgh1DEBoA).

Comment: Where is `obj`?

Comment: Cut and paste fail :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be unsafe. If something has type `string` at runtime, it doesn't mean that it has the same static type, e.g. it could be some enum: `'Foo' | 'Bar'`, so making it just `string` would allow unsafe mutations. On the other hand, it could be `number | string`, so in the future `head` could become a number or any type, really.

Instead you can do the following:

```
const refineToResponse = (value: mixed): ?Response => {   
  if (value
    && typeof value === "object"
    && typeof value.head === "string") {

    return { head: value.head };   
  }

  return null; 
};
```

Comment: Ah, the discussion of mutation makes sense. You're saying that elsewhere it the code I could mutate the original `value` object and break my typed `response` which should be of a known type.

Cheers!

Comment: Should it be possible to return a shallow copy of `value` instead of listing every property in the response object?  Something like `return Object.assign({}, value)` or `return { ...value }`.